# Has anyone used oTool commands through XCode command line tools ?

Tags: xcode, otool

Has anyone used oTool commands  through XCode command line tools ? 
I want to check Stack protection flag setting using oTool for an iPAd app.

Comment: What did you try already? Can you share your attempts with us?

Comment: I have installed XCode command line tools. I tried to SSH into iPad using terminal on MAC. But no success. Also, tried to fire few oTool commands on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

otool -Iv $app_binary_path |grep stack_chk